# Onclick funcs is not working properly in my function

Tags: php

I have written the function for updating my status from 0 to 1 but when I am clicking on button its updating the status of all the rows. I don't know what I did wrong.

```
function updateStatusenable($id,$value)
{
global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE gb_users
    SET status = ?
    WHERE
    id = ?
    LIMIT 1
    ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $id,$value);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
return $result;
}
```

And this function I used in:

```
 <?php
    $value=1;
    foreach($users as $v1)
     {
        echo "<tr>
        <form action=\"admin_pending_approval_users.php\" method=\"post\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"enable\" value=".$v1['id'].">
        <td>".$v1['id']."</td>
        <td>".getAccountTypeNameById($v1['account_type'])."</td>
        <td>".$v1['name']."</td>
        <td>".$v1['user_name']."</td>
        <td>".getUserGroupsNameById($v1['group'])."</td>
        <td>Rs.".fetchUserBalance($v1['id'])."</td>
        <td>";
        if($v1['status']==1)
            {
            echo "<button class=\"green tiny\"><span>ACTIVE</span></button>";
            }
                else
                {
                    echo "<button class=\"orange tiny\" onclick=".updateStatusenable($v1['id'],$value)." ><span>DISABLED</span></button>";
                }
                echo "</td>
                <td align='right'>
                <a href='view_user.php?user_id=".$v1['id']."'><button class=\"small\"><img src=\"images/icons/small/white/magnifying_glass.png\"></button></a>
                <a href='edit_user.php?user_id=".$v1['id']."'><button class=\"small\"><img src=\"images/icons/small/white/create_write.png\"></button></a>
                </td>
                </form>
                </tr>";
                    }
```

Comment: No. Just no. You _can not_ call a serer side php function from a client side javascript handler. How should that work? Instead you need to implement an AJAX request to relay between both separate systems.

Comment: i got your point. Can you help me how i should achieve this??

Comment: I already answered to that in my last comment, didn't I? You need to implement an AJAX request.

Comment: Okay, I try doing it

Answer (score 0):

I think your binding order is wrong when you set it like below;

`$stmt->bind_param("ss", $id,$value);`

instead use

`$stmt->bind_param("ss",$value, $id);`

as u set status before id

Also use ajax to update so you can send requests for your actions from client to server.

Comment: Well spotted, good point. However this is not the issue the OP currently faces, so this does _not_ answer the question asked.

Comment: Its not working. Its changing the status of all the row

Comment: @arkascha true i have spotted it and wrote as answer. I guess i should have just commended this.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz You can still do so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As i dont want to use Ajax I have done some changes like and make it done in PHP.

```
<?php
                    $value=1;
                    foreach($users as $v1)
                    {
                        echo "<tr>
                        <form action=\"admin_pending_approval_users.php\" method=\"post\">
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=".$v1['id'].">
                            <td>".$v1['id']."</td>
                            <td>".getAccountTypeNameById($v1['account_type'])."</td>
                            <td>".$v1['name']."</td>
                            <td>".$v1['user_name']."</td>
                            <td>".getUserGroupsNameById($v1['group'])."</td>
                            <td>Rs.".fetchUserBalance($v1['id'])."</td>
                            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"process\" value=\"1\" required>
                            <td>";
                                if($v1['status']==1)
                                {
                                    echo "<button class=\"green tiny\"><span>ACTIVE</span></button>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<button class=\"orange tiny\" onClick=\"form.submit()\" ><span>DISABLED</span></button>";
                                }
                                echo "</td>

                            <td align='right'>
                                <a href='view_user.php?user_id=".$v1['id']."'><button class=\"small\"><img src=\"images/icons/small/white/magnifying_glass.png\"></button></a>
                                <a href='edit_user.php?user_id=".$v1['id']."'><button class=\"small\"><img src=\"images/icons/small/white/create_write.png\"></button></a>
                            </td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>";
                    }

                    ?>
```

And in the same php page i added one function as

```
if(!empty($_POST['process']))
{
$id = $_POST['id'];
updateStatusenable($id,1);
 }
```

And in the end the funcs its remain same

Comment: Sure, possible, but that means a full page reload. Very ugly.